# react-native bridge for location permission prompts twice

Tags: java, android, react-native, react-native-bridge

I am using react-native 0.59, then updated the API to 29.
Changing 29, the 'Allow all the time' was removed in the option list upon requesting for location permission.

Then, I created a bridge for the location permission. Because some articles, stated that I need to list the option manually.

```
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getReactApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);
        
        
        if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            promise.resolve(true);
        } else {
            // Intent i = new Intent(mClass.this, GeoLocationService.class);
            final Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
            
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                },
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION
            );
            
            promise.resolve(false);
        }
```

It is working.
But on debug mode it prompts once, but on release mode it prompts twice.

[image]

[image]

Thanks for your response!